Camera Shake Issue in UE5
I'm experiencing unexpected camera behavior while implementing a camera shake effect in my first-person project. After adding the camera shake, the camera is not behaving correctly (the camera is not correctly positioned or following the player). Are there specific techniques to properly attach the camera shake to the player's view? I'd appreciate any guidance on troubleshooting and correctly implementing camera shake setup. Any code snippets or blueprint configurations that could help resolve this issue would be extremely helpful.
I used this doc: Camera Shakes | Unreal Engine 4.27 Documentation | Epic Developer Community
Video: 07.12.2024 11_51.webm - Google Диск

It's usually best to assume that off-site links will not get clicked. Can you edit your question to explain in the body of the post itself how you've set up your camera's follow and shake behaviours? Include any relevant code, blueprint graphs, or actor/asset configuration.
